# File rename numbers with letters

Tags: batch-file

can someone help to write a batch to raname all files in a folders like this:
Origin file: TEST_0123654.wav
Output file: TEST_ABCDGFE.waw

so, with conversion 0=A 1=B 2=C....

Thanks

Comment: Helping you to write a batch file implies that you did some research on your own, so please share your efforts! We are not going to write a script for you! Regard that StackOverflow is not a free code writing service! Read at least the entire [tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to use this site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `substitution` :

```
@echo off
set "$test=toto_1234"

set "$test=%$test:1=A%"
set "$test=%$test:2=B%"
set "$test=%$test:3=C%"
set "$test=%$test:4=D%"

echo %$test%
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks SachaDee Trying to use this in my script I have now:

```
 Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

 Set "Pattern1=0"
 Set "Replace1=A"

 Set "Pattern2=1"
 Set "Replace2=B"

 Set "Pattern3=2"
 Set "Replace3=C"

 Set "Pattern4=3"
 Set "Replace4=D"

 Set "Pattern5=4"
 Set "Replace5=E"

 Set "Pattern6=5"
 Set "Replace6=F"

 Set "Pattern7=6"
 Set "Replace7=G"

 Set "Pattern8=7"
 Set "Replace8=H"

 Set "Pattern9=8"
 Set "Replace9=I"

 Set "Pattern10=9"
 Set "Replace10=L"


 For %%a in (*.wav) Do (
      Set "File=%%~a"
 Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern1%=%Replace1%!"
 Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern2%=%Replace2%!"
 Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern3%=%Replace3%!"
 Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern4%=%Replace4%!"
 Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern5%=%Replace5%!"
 Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern6%=%Replace6%!"
 Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern7%=%Replace7%!"
 Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern8%=%Replace8%!"
 Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern9%=%Replace9%!"
 Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern10%=%Replace10%!"
 )
```

The problem is that if I run this, it will convert only 0 and 1. I have to run 7 or 8 times to complete all convertion. Where is the error? Thanks

Comment: your (logical) failure is `ren "%%a" ...` `%%a` is always the same filename (non-existent after the first `rename`). First, do the ten substitutions to a string, then just rename once.